# Drag and drop items between list and save their position in a php file

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have to build a solution which includes being able to drag and drop items from one list to others.

Basically I have a static list "subjects" which contains a few subjects and it could look like below.

```
<ul id="subjects" class="sortable_list connectedSortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">ID 1 - Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">ID 2 - Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">ID 3 - Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">ID 4 - Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">ID 5 - Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Based on a variable `$session` which is an `int` I have to create i.e if `$session=2` automatically two other sortable lists like below:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= $session; $x++) {
    echo "<ul id='sortable."$x".' class='sortable_list connectedSortable'>
    </ul>";
}
```

What I want to do, is after dropping subjects from the `#subjects` I want to save in a php file the ID's of the items in each sortable list created automatically from the for loop and also the order of the files.

I want to use jquery-ui sortable, or if you have any suggestion please do so.
I would appreciate some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: well for a start your going to need to learn AJAX

Comment: Have a look here http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

Answer (score 0):

here's what you'll have to use: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

Choose the correct IDs eg ( change `id='sortable."$x"'` to `sortable_"$x"` in your code and what you'll get is a string of ordered IDs in the format `sortable[]=1&sortable[]=5&sortable[]=2` .

Then you can split this string and manipulate it and use it accordingly.